# Spring Framework ModelAndView: 404 page not found, reference to view with name 'index'; model is null

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am new to the Spring framework, and I have problem when following tutorial of Spring 3.2.3. I am trying to return a jsp page using ModelAndView but when I passed the name of the page (index.jsp), it returns that the reference to the index is null.

I have checked that the index.jsp is located in the correct directory ("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp")

the following are the configurations:

```
@Controller
public class NavigationController {

    @RequestMapping(value={"/", "index"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView homePage() {
        ModelAndView _result= new ModelAndView("index");
        return _result;
    }
}
```

the _result is "reference to view with name 'index'; model is null"

for more detail Initializer class

```
public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(WebAppConfig.class);
    ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);      
    registerHiddenHttpMethodFilter(servletContext); 

    Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME, new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
    servlet.addMapping("/");
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);

}

private void registerHiddenHttpMethodFilter(ServletContext servletContext) {
    FilterRegistration.Dynamic fr = servletContext
            .addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter", HiddenHttpMethodFilter.class);
    fr.addMappingForServletNames(
            EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD), 
            false, 
            DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME);
}
```

then WebAppConfig Class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.eko")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.eko.repository")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

@Resource
private Environment env;

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));

    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibProperties());

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

private Properties hibProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
    properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
    return properties;  
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.favorPathExtension(true)
        .useJaf(false)
        .ignoreAcceptHeader(true)
        .mediaType("html", MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
        .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .defaultContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver(
        ContentNegotiationManager manager) {

    List<ViewResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<ViewResolver>();

    InternalResourceViewResolver r1 = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    r1.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    r1.setSuffix(".jsp");
    r1.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    resolvers.add(r1);

    JsonViewResolver r2 = new JsonViewResolver();
    resolvers.add(r2);

    ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
    resolver.setViewResolvers(resolvers);
    resolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);
    return resolver;

}

/**
* View resolver for returning JSON in a view-based system. Always returns a
* {@link MappingJacksonJsonView}.
*/
public class JsonViewResolver implements ViewResolver {
    public View resolveViewName(String viewName, Locale locale)
            throws Exception {
            MappingJacksonJsonView view = new MappingJacksonJsonView();
            view.setPrettyPrint(true);
            return view;
    }
}
```

}

and the folder src/main/webapp is as the following

--src/main/webapp 
----META-INF 
------MANIFEST.MF 
----WEB-INF 
------lib 
------pages 
--------index.jsp 
------web.xml

The environment use JDK 1.7 and apache Tomcat 7.0

and the following is the jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
   <P> HELLO WORLD </P>
</body>
</html>
```

View Resolver

I found that it the index.jsp is located on the wrong directory. In the war the generated directory are as following:

```
--MVCSpring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
----META-INF
----WEB-INF
------classes
--------com
--------META-INF
--------WEB-INF
----------pages
------------index.jsp
----------web.xml
--------application.properties
------lib
```

But i can't figure out why it's generated like that

Comment: try to remove the .jsp part on your view name. leave it at `index`

Comment: try to pass "index" rather than "index.jsp". You already manage the suffix in your configuration.

Comment: done, changed it to index only, but still doesn't work

Comment: by the way, i added the JSP page i have.

Comment: Can you please post the error/exception message.

Comment: there is no exception generated, in the statement
 ModelAndView _result= new ModelAndView("index");
_result is  "reference to view with name 'index'; model is null"

Comment: What does your view resolver look like? Try to return String "index" instead of ModelAndView("index") like `public String homePage() { return "index" }`

Comment: The view resolver (you can find in the class WebAppConfig up.

Comment: I tried to return String instead, and i still doesn't work.

Comment: I found a something that might help. I am using Eclipse Mars, and after I do Maven Install, in the folder target, the jsp pages are located in fact in the wrong directory.

Comment: I cannot understand where the problem lies. You create the model and view as `new ModelAndView("index");` and **as expected** get a *"reference to view with name 'index'; model is null"*. The javadoc for this constructor says *Convenient constructor when there is no model data to expose*: you give no model and get no model...

Comment: It is my mistake . The problem is i got 404 , It turns out that the jsp is misplaced in the war.